# Роль Purchasing server во внутриигровых покупках Steam SDK

Tags: c++, cocos2d, steam-web-api

Доброе время суток!
Необходимо реализовать интеграцию внутриигровых покупок для Стима. Почитав документацию (англ слабо знаю), не складывается все в общую картину.

https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/MicroTxn

Стим предлагает производить покупки в несколько этапов, через "Your purchasing server". Для каких целей он служит и можно ли обойтись без него?

Comment: Во первых, по твоей ссылке может перейти только тот у кого есть аккаунт разработчика на стиме. Во вторых, там в самом низу страницы есть ссылка на форум обсуждения этого вопроса, лучше обратиться туда. И конечно же учить английский, без этого на стиме никуда :)

Comment: Спасибо, за интерес. Да, доступ предоставляется только разработчикам, может поэтому так мало информации. В этом была и суть вопроса, может кто поделиться, у кого был опыт.)